# constructors of my string C++

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

I know that if something in the constructor fails, I must throw an exception. Does this mean everytime I use 'new' inside of my constructors, when I create an object of this class I should initialise it in the 'try' 'catch' block?

```
try{
mystring s("test");
}
catch(std::ba .....)
{...........}
```

I know that is almost impossible 'new' to fail, but what I'm asking is, if my constructor throws something, is this the right way to catch it? (because I've never seen someone using it when creating an object)

Comment: It means that you need run a google search for the keyword "RAII".

Comment: `I know that if something in the constructor fails, I must throw an exception` - Where did you learn this?

Comment: @EdHeal It is the idiomatic way of signaling a problem during construction.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  I read it, but my question remains, if the constructor throws an exception, you should handle it somewhere, right?

Comment: Well, yes, thrown exceptions should be handled. Otherwise execution will terminate. And, of course, if the intent for the thrown exception is precisely that, to terminate the application, then nothing needs to be done, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You really should *not* be putting a `try{}catch{}` round every statement like that. The beauty of *exceptions* is, when used correctly, that you don't have to worry about exception for an whole area of code that can not function if one of its components fails. Don't check the individual statements, check the entire sub-section of code.

```
try
{
    // good chunk of code that requires everything to succeed

    object o1; // if this fails we can't continue

    auto o2 = o1.func(); // if this fails we can't continue
    auto o3 = o2.func(); // if this fails we can't continue

    return o3; // yay we got there
}
catch(const std::exception& e)
{
    // that entire task failed because e.what(), tell the user and move on
}
```

The crucial thing is to ensure your objects clean themselves up in their destructors when an exception is thrown. That is the [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) approach.

Comment: Thank you, that made it clear to me. One last thing, how to ensure that my objects clean themselvese up? If an exception is thrown, doesn't it call the destructor?

Comment: That does really depend on what the developer would like to do if an exception is thrown. If it possible to recover from the exception, the developer might want to check each invidual statements. If not, yes then it should be the chunk of code that is affected by the exception. Also I guess it might be worth mentioning [noexcept specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) for c++11.

Comment: @user5692938, if an exception is thrown out of a block of code, all the objects local to this block created so far are properly destructed (including any enclosing block, and so forth, until the exception is caught, or it has been propagated to the top level where global objects live). This is why destructors are `noexcept` and are not expected to throw anything. If an exception is thrown out of an object constructor, everything created so far, all the object's bases and fields and local objects of the ctor's body are guaranteed to be destructed as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that if something in the constructor fails, I must throw an
>   exception.

You *should* throw an exception. But **only if *you* detect the failure**, not if somebody else has already thrown something, because in that case the failure detection has already happened elsewhere.

> Does this mean everytime I use 'new' inside of my constructors, when I
>   create an object of this class I should initialise it in the 'try'
>   'catch' block?

No.

First of all, you should rarely use `new` in your code anyway. Memory management is best left to `std::vector`, `std::string` or other container classes, or to `std::unique_ptr` or other smart pointers, depending on the features you require.

Second, if `new` fails or if memory allocation inside of a standard-container class fails, then throwing an exception from the constructor is your least concern, because that will happen automatically due to `new` throwing `std::bad_alloc`. In other words, it is `new` (or the container class) which detects the failure, not you.

What you can do is to translate the exception to another type:

```
Example::Example()
{
    try
    {
        std::string some_local_string(arg);
        // ...
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc const& exc)
    {
        throw MyCustomException(exc);
    }
}
```

However, such an exception translation is usually not worth the trouble, especially with `std::bad_alloc`, which is hard to handle meaningfully anyway.

A much bigger problem may be the fact that the destructor will never be called, so any `delete`s for previous `new` allocations saved in member pointers will never happen, creating a memory leak.

Again, use `std::vector`, `std::string`, `std::unique_ptr` or other such standard classes to avoid those problems!

> ```
> try{
> mystring s("test");
> }
> catch(std::ba .....)
> {...........}
> ```

This piece of code has nothing to do with `new`. If `mystring` is a string class, then that class hopefully performs its own memory management. Of course, you should not use a custom string class but `std::string`.

> I know that is almost impossible 'new' to fail

Don't be overly optimistic. It's a very good idea to care about error handling! :)

> if my constructor throws something, is this the right way to catch it?

No.

If you correctly use all the tools which C++ provides, then neither `new` nor `try` and `catch` or even custom destructors will be seen very often in your code.

```
class Example
{
public:
    Example()
    {
        std::string s("test");
        // no try-catch

        // ...
    }

    // no destructor

    // ...

private:
    std::string member1;
    std::vector<int> member2;
};
```

Comment: "This piece of code has nothing to do with new. If mystring is a string class, then that class hopefully performs its own memory management."
What do you mean by that? How can I manage to handle an exception inside the constructor?

Comment: @user5692938: I mean that `mystring` hopefully has a destructor that handles failures automatically. Why do you insist on "handling" an out-of-memory error in a constructor?

Comment: I don insist anything , I'm just not sure how things happen. If  i have a constructor that looks like this

T::T()
{
   test = new char [5000] // test is a char*, and what if constructor throws bad alloc here, wouldn't this exception go to where the object is tried to be created?
}

Comment: @user5692938: Yes, the exception would be thrown to the caller of the constructor. Note that the caller will likely not handle that exception, either. This is because most levels of your code will never handle any exception but just let it be thrown through. In fact, that's one of the reasons exceptions are useful in the first place - you do not need to "handle" them everywhere.