# Initializing object which throws exceptions

Tags: c++

I have class A, which has constructor A(string filepath)

```
class A {
  public:
    A(string filePath);
  private:
    A();
}
```

I need to initialize A, and use it later. Constructor A throws exceptions.

```
int main() {
    A a;
    try {
        a = A("./my/file/path");
    } catch (exception e) {
        return 1;
    }
    // Use a
    return 0;
}
```

What would be the most elegant solution? (I dont want to have something like init function, because it makes it possible to have empty A object.)

Comment: Just put all your code (apart from the failure branch) inside the `try` block. That way everything after the declaration of `a` can depend on it being correctly-initialized.

Comment: `try { A a("./my/path"); //use a; } catch( std::exception& e ) { return 1; }`

Comment: You haven't stated what is wrong with the solution you presented (catch by const-reference missing notwithstanding). You know the construction of `a` isn't the *only* thing that can be in that try-block, *right* ?

Comment: I would like to check if there is exception before I use it.

Comment: @Etwus Do as Useless said. If you're still in the try-block after construction, then an exception wasn't thrown.

Comment: Ah, so try-catch will catch exception right after exception is thrown? Not after end of try block?

Comment: @Etwus excactly, as soon as a exception is thrown the program will 'stop' and go to the first catch block it can find. If it can't find one the program will crash. If you are new i recommend reading up on assert, too.

Comment: Don't wrap your `try{}catch{}` round just one statement. wrap it round **all** the code that depends on the object being valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238422/constructors-of-my-string-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most elegant solution is probably to move all your logic which uses `a` into a function

```
int use_a(A &a);

int main() {
    try {
        A a("./my/file/path");
        // if we reach here, no exception was thrown
        // hence a is safe to use
        return use_a(a);
    } catch (exception e) {
        // if we reach here a never really existed
        return 1;
    }
}
```

You're correct to prefer avoiding two-phase initialization - this way `use_a` can implicitly rely on `a` being safe to use.

Comment: You can remove some indentation by moving the `try` to function scope : `int main() try { stuff.. } catch (const exception& e) { error handling... }`

Comment: You can, but I'm not certain it's clearer (cue further questions about function try/catch ...)

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant solution is:

```
int main() {
   try {
      A a("...");
      // use a
   } catch (const std::exception& e) {
      // log e
      return 1;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want empty A objects consider deleting the default constructor. Note that this makes using some stl containers more difficult, while ensuring no invalid object exists.

In addition to that i think using throw in constructors very much allowed. If you don't want to do that consider the noexcept keyword. Note that throws in destructors can cause problems and are usually avoided.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, you might turn the exception in "optional/checkable" construction with `std::optional` or `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::optional<A> MakeA(const std::filesystem::path& path)
{
    try {
        return A{path};
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
}

int main() {
    auto a = MakeA("./my/file/path");
    if (!a) {
        return 1;
    }
    // Use *a
    return 0;
}
```